# JAVA string encoding conversion issues

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a piece of code working fine when started in netbeans (this code replaces some string in content.xml file extracted from .odt file):

```
String cont = new String(Utils.readBinaryFile(path + "/content.xml"));
for (Patterns p : patterns) {
    cont = cont.replaceAll(p.search.replaceAll("\\{", "\\\\{"), p.replace.replaceAll("\n", "<text:line-break/>").replaceAll("\\{", "\\\\{"));
}
Utils.saveToFile(path + "/content.xml", cont.getBytes("UTF-8"), false);
```

and

```
/**
 * Saves the binary data to the file, if append is FALSE, the data in the file is overwritten
 * @param fileName
 * @param data
 * @param append 
 */
    public static void saveToFile(String fileName, byte[] data, boolean append) {
    try {
        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName, append)) {
        out.write(data);
        }
    } catch (IOException iOException) {
        System.err.println(iOException.getMessage());
    }
    }
```

If I use the code in Windows in command line like java -jar .... the characters saved in the file have broken conversion.
I realize that it comes from fact that windows works in my case in encoding CP1250 and when I start my code as java -jar the CP1250 is used.The question is how to make this working fine? I do not use that code in command line, but in applet and code run from the applet behaves exactly like the one run from command line in CP1250.

I read many articles about encoding but nothing seemed to help me, but running from command line with specified encoding:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar Office.jar
```

solved the issue.

Realizing that I then wanted to pass arguments to my applet tag:

```
<object classid='clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93' width='500' height='30'> 
    <param name='codebase_lookup' value='false'> 
    <param name='archive' value='" . ServerURL . "/applets/Office/Office.jar'> 
    <param name='code' value='OfficeApplet'> 
    <param name='java_arguments' value='-Dfile.encoding=utf-8'
    <param name='data' value='" . $dataJSON . "'> 
    <comment> 
        <embed 
            codebase_lookup='false' 
            archive='" . ServerURL . "/applets/Office/Office.jar' 
            code='OfficeApplet' 
            width='500' 
            height='30'
            java_arguments='-Dfile.encoding=utf-8'
            data='" . $dataJSON. "' 
            type='application/x-java-applet' 
        > 
            <noembed> 
              You need JRE 1.7+
            </noembed> 
          </embed> 
        </comment> 
</object>
```

As you can see I am using **java_arguments** tag but it doesn't seem to help or maybe java_arguments are passed to JVM in wrong way or arguments are ignored, I don't know. Can somebody help me please solve that issue? I use windows 7 64 bit.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

```
String cont = new String(Utils.readBinaryFile(path + "/content.xml"));
```

The [`String(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D%29) constructor converts bytes to characters using the platform default encoding, which can be anything. The easiest fix is to use a constructor that permits specifying the encoding; for example:

```
String cont = new String(Utils.readBinaryFile(path + "/content.xml"), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I was sure I did the same and still had problems with encoding (I had a commented line). 
Then I realized I made the mistake. In the original code I wrote
String cont = new String(Utils.readBinaryFile(path+ "/content.xml","UTF-8"));

instead of 

String cont = new String(Utils.readBinaryFile(path+ "/content.xml"),"UTF-8");

very similar, but only the second one is doing conversion in the right way.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Utils.readBinaryFile(path + "/content.xml")` probably doesn't use UTF-8 encoding to read the data from the file. My guess is that you're using the default encoding in the util method and this changes from system to system.

What you need to do to fix this is to specify the encoding of the file in `readBinaryFile()`.

`InputStreamReader` is your friend.

Comment: Unfortunately, the encoding of the input file can change, I don't want to force this. I found the BUG in my code thanks to the second answer sent by Joni, anyway thank you for your time and suggestion.